# Происхождение слова "скрижаль"

Tags: этимология

Скрижалями называют каменные таблички с какими-то важными надписями. Например, скрижали Завета, где были написаны десять заповедей.
А каково происхождение слова "скрижаль"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Скрижаль** - заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где оно является суф. производным от утраченного скрига, суф. образования от (с)кра «груда, камень». Того же корня, что сербохорв. крижити «резать, рассекать». Скрижаль первично — «рассеченная плита».**

Comment: >Того же корня, что сербохорв. крижити «резать, рассекать».

Вспоминается какое-то слово "отчекрыжить", т.е. отрезать. Это наверное слово от того же корня?

Answer (score 0):

> Скрижаль первично — «рассеченная плита».

Задумался. А может быть это **плита, на которой что-то высечено** ? Вырезана надпись? Т.е. слова настолько важные и ценные, с непреходящей ценностью, что их можно вырезать на камне -- таком материале, на котором хоть и трудно что-то писать, но который может храниться столетиями.